# how to set the x position of the back bar button item in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a I-phone application.But there is a problem with setting the x position of the back bar button item .Please need help in this Regard.

Comment: you should provide some more details. code, screenshots... something that helps identifying your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can customize navigation bar, then you can locate the back button.
2. if you use the default UI, just put a image or some text there. can not set x position.